# wsimport import fails with NCBI/Blast

Tags: java, bioinformatics, wsimport, blast, ncbi

I'm trying to generate the files handling the SOAP services documented here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK55699/

But wsimport fails:

```
 $ wsimport -d generated "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/netblast/blastws.cgi?WSDL"
parsing WSDL...


[ERROR] Schema descriptor {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov}Blast4-queue-search-request-lite in message part "request" is not defined and could not be bound to Java. Perhaps the schema descriptor {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov}Blast4-queue-search-request-lite is not defined in the schema imported/included in the WSDL. You can either add such imports/includes or run wsimport and provide the schema location using -b switch.
  line 15 of http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/blast/netblast/blastws.cgi?WSDL
```

However, the WSDL validators I tested didn't show any error ( http://xmethods.net/ve2/Tools.po , http://www.validwsdl.com/ ...)

How can I fix this problem ?

Thanks,